# Why does createCapture not work when I run the code?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

The project I'm working on should have the code createCapture but it doesn't work when I run the code despite having a createCapture() in the code.

When I run it, I would click to the second page and there should be a createCapture on the second page.
The camera should turn on, When Clicking to the second page

The JS Code:

```js
let screen = 0;
let saveB;
let fullB;
let capture;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(400,400);
}


function draw() {
    if(screen == 0) {
        startScreen();
    } else if(screen == 1) {
        mainScreen();
    } else if(screen == 2) {
        endScreen();
    }
}

function startScreen() {
    background(100);
    fill(250);
    text('Here you are', width / 2, height /2);
    text('Click to Start', width / 2, height / 2 + 20);
    textAlign(CENTER);
}

function mousePressed() {
    if(screen == 0) {
        screen = 1;
    } else if(screen == 2) {
        screen = 0;
    }
}


function mainScreen() {
    background(100, 200, 250);
    text('This is you ', 40, 30);
    saveB = createButton('Save');
    saveB.mousePressed(Savefile);

    fullB = createButton('FullScreen');
    fullB.mousePressed(FullScreen);

    capture = createCapture('VIDEO');
    capture.position(200,200);
    capture.size(100, 100);
    let audio = createCapture('AUDIO');
}

function Savefile() {
    save('Photo.jpg');
}

function FullScreen() {
    let fs = fullscreen
    fullscreen(!fs);
}

function endScreen() {
    background(100,200,200);
    fill(250);
    text('Thank you for looking at yourself', width / 2, height / 2);
    text('Click to restart', width / 2, height / 2 + 20);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The createCapture should appear on the second page but it doesn't. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a typo in the 2nd line of your code: `let, saveB;`

Comment: Oh thank you I didnt see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you don't have permission to access the camera in the context where you are using this code. If your code is running in an iframe on another website it may have restrictions that prevent it from even requesting access to the webcam.

Other than that your code mostly works. However, when you get to screen 1 (a.k.a. mainScreen) you are currently recreating the buttons and capture every frame, which is not what you want to do. Both buttons and capture objects are persistent, so you only need to create them once.

Additionally, while your code displays the webcam video on the screen it will not be present in the file generated when you click saved. This is because creating a capture object doesn't actually draw the captured images to your canvas. Instead you need to hide the capture object and draw it as an image to the canvas. Here is a [working version of your code hosted on p5js.org](https://editor.p5js.org/Kumu-Paul/sketches/reYgO_cqg). And bellow is an abridge version with just the relevant bits:

```
let saveB;
let capture;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  mainScreen();
}

let mainScreenInitialized = false;

function mainScreen() {
  if (!mainScreenInitialized) {
    mainScreenInitialized = true;
    background(100, 200, 250);
    text('This is you ', 40, 30);
    
    saveB = createButton('Save');
    saveB.mousePressed(Savefile);

    capture = createCapture('VIDEO');
    capture.hide();
  }
  
  let aspect = capture.height / capture.width;
  image(capture, 100, 100, 200, 200 * aspect);
}

function Savefile() {
  save('Photo.jpg');
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot make this into a snippet on StackOverflow because the iframe it runs in does not have permission to request webcam access.